# FTP File Delete failing after Rename

Tags: ftp, deleting

I have a 3rd party connector (ION) that is sending files via FTP and due to failures, it seems they are running an RNFR command, followed by a RNTO command, and finally a DELE command on the original file name.  This is where it's failing.   Logs are below.  They are responding to requests for troubleshooting by telling me it's something on my end.  I'm not sure what it could be, though.
TIA.

```
2020-01-30 14:42:25,074 DEBUG FTPSession [Session.2190685:Default Site:CarrollCo2018:EXTERNAL_IP_ADDRESS] setting state to AwaitCommand 
2020-01-30 14:42:25,074 DEBUG FTPConnection [Session.2190685:Default Site:CarrollCo2018:EXTERNAL_IP_ADDRESS] BeginSend: Response 22071166 
2020-01-30 14:42:25,074 DEBUG FTPConnection [Session.2190685:Default Site:CarrollCo2018:EXTERNAL_IP_ADDRESS] OnSend: Response 22071166 
2020-01-30 14:42:25,105 DEBUG FTPConnection [Session.2190685:Default Site:CarrollCo2018:EXTERNAL_IP_ADDRESS] CMD> RNFR /Error/validationLocationTest1580413344681.inprocess 
2020-01-30 14:42:25,105 DEBUG FTPConnection [Session.2190685:Default Site:CarrollCo2018:EXTERNAL_IP_ADDRESS] Processed command RNFR /Error/validationLocationTest1580413344681.inprocess 
2020-01-30 14:42:25,105 DEBUG FTPConnection [Session.2190685:Default Site:CarrollCo2018:EXTERNAL_IP_ADDRESS] CMD< 350 File or directory exists, ready for destination name. 
2020-01-30 14:42:25,105 DEBUG FTPSession [Session.2190685:Default Site:CarrollCo2018:EXTERNAL_IP_ADDRESS] setting state to Rename 
2020-01-30 14:42:25,105 DEBUG FTPConnection [Session.2190685:Default Site:CarrollCo2018:EXTERNAL_IP_ADDRESS] BeginSend: Response 22071167 
2020-01-30 14:42:25,105 DEBUG FTPConnection [Session.2190685:Default Site:CarrollCo2018:EXTERNAL_IP_ADDRESS] OnSend: Response 22071167 
2020-01-30 14:42:25,121 DEBUG FTPConnection [Session.2190685:Default Site:CarrollCo2018:EXTERNAL_IP_ADDRESS] CMD> RNTO /Error/validationLocationTest 
2020-01-30 14:42:25,121 INFO RenameCommand [Session.2190685:Default Site:CarrollCo2018:EXTERNAL_IP_ADDRESS] Renamed file from /F-drive/CompleteFTP/CarrollCo2018/Error/validationLocationTest1580413344681.inprocess to /F-drive/CompleteFTP/CarrollCo2018/Error/validationLocationTest 
2020-01-30 14:42:25,121 DEBUG FTPConnection [Session.2190685:Default Site:CarrollCo2018:EXTERNAL_IP_ADDRESS] Processed command RNTO /Error/validationLocationTest 
2020-01-30 14:42:25,121 DEBUG FTPConnection [Session.2190685:Default Site:CarrollCo2018:EXTERNAL_IP_ADDRESS] CMD< 250 Rename successful. 
2020-01-30 14:42:25,121 DEBUG FTPSession [Session.2190685:Default Site:CarrollCo2018:EXTERNAL_IP_ADDRESS] setting state to AwaitCommand 
2020-01-30 14:42:25,121 DEBUG FTPConnection [Session.2190685:Default Site:CarrollCo2018:EXTERNAL_IP_ADDRESS] BeginSend: Response 22071168 
2020-01-30 14:42:25,121 DEBUG FTPConnection [Session.2190685:Default Site:CarrollCo2018:EXTERNAL_IP_ADDRESS] OnSend: Response 22071168 
2020-01-30 14:42:25,152 DEBUG FTPConnection [Session.2190685:Default Site:CarrollCo2018:EXTERNAL_IP_ADDRESS] CMD> DELE /Error/validationLocationTest1580413344681.inprocess 
2020-01-30 14:42:25,152 ERROR DeleteCommand [Session.2190685:Default Site:CarrollCo2018:EXTERNAL_IP_ADDRESS] failed to delete file: validationLocationTest1580413344681.inprocess 
2020-01-30 14:42:25,152 DEBUG FTPConnection [Session.2190685:Default Site:CarrollCo2018:EXTERNAL_IP_ADDRESS] Processed command DELE /Error/validationLocationTest1580413344681.inprocess 
2020-01-30 14:42:25,152 DEBUG FTPConnection [Session.2190685:Default Site:CarrollCo2018:EXTERNAL_IP_ADDRESS] CMD< 550 /Error/validationLocationTest1580413344681.inprocess: No such file or direct 
2020-01-30 14:42:25,152 DEBUG FTPConnection [Session.2190685:Default Site:CarrollCo2018:EXTERNAL_IP_ADDRESS] [+4 chars] 
2020-01-30 14:42:25,152 DEBUG FTPSession [Session.2190685:Default Site:CarrollCo2018:EXTERNAL_IP_ADDRESS] setting state to AwaitCommand 
2020-01-30 14:42:25,152 DEBUG FTPConnection [Session.2190685:Default Site:CarrollCo2018:EXTERNAL_IP_ADDRESS] OnSend: Response 22071169 
2020-01-30 14:42:25,152 DEBUG FTPConnection [Session.2190685:Default Site:CarrollCo2018:EXTERNAL_IP_ADDRESS] BeginSend: Response 22071169 
2020-01-30 14:42:25,168 DEBUG FTPConnection [Session.2190685:Default Site:CarrollCo2018:EXTERNAL_IP_ADDRESS] CMD> QUIT
```

Comment: Deleting a file that does not exist anymore obviously fails. I do not understand what is the question.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, that was what I though, but the way they pushed it back to my group had me second guessing myself and I was hoping for either enlightenment or confirmation.  Thanks.